# How does this synchronization algorithm work?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization

```
do { while (test_and_set(&lock))
; /* do nothing */
/* critical section */
lock = false;
/* remainder section */
} while (true);



boolean test_and_set (boolean *target)
{
boolean rv = *target;
*target = TRUE;
return rv:
}
```

I don't understand how it's supposed to work, because regardless of what while (test_and_set(&lock) returns, whether it be true or false, the do{} code will still run the critical section. It will do nothing and then immediately run the critical section, so how does that help synchronize the threads?

Comment: This is clearly not thread-safe. Who says that it is?

Comment: the `while( test_and_set( &lock ) );` will loop until it becomes false and then it will run the critical section. Don't really understand what `test_and_set` is doing though

Comment: Is this on any specific platform you're targeting? because there are platform intrinsics that will likely do this *correctly* for you. To answer your question of how this works, frankly, *it doesn't* (certainly not reliably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not regardless of what `test_and_set` returns. Note that `test_and_set` returns the previous value of the location given to it, so `while(test_and_set(&lock));` (note the terminating semicolon!) will spin on the CPU while another thread "owns" the lock.

Note, however, that your actual implementation of `test_and_set` is not atomic and, therefore, not actually threadsafe.

Perhaps it helps if I reformat your code to look like this?

```
do {
    while (test_and_set(&lock)) {
        /* do nothing */
    }
    /* critical section */
    lock = false;
    /* remainder section */
} while (true);
```

Comment: So if it's lock = true, it does nothing and if lock = false it runs the critical section and then put lock to false so another thread can run it? How would you make it atomic though?

Comment: You can't make it atomic using only C code. You need some or some other form of lower-level support, like bus-locking instructions or (on uni-processor machines) interrupt disabling. Such things are often provided by standard libraries, but they are specific for every platform, so there's no universal answer without knowing the platform.